# Why method in PolicyManager directly return null in Android-22 Source Code?

Tags: android

I am recently try to read android source code .I have two set of source code the android-22 and the android-21. i find some differneces between these .
below is a piece of the PolicyManager's source code ,i think it is with big problem!
public class PolicyManager {

```
public static Window makeNewWindow(Context context) {
    // this will likely crash somewhere beyond so we log it.
    Bridge.getLog().error(LayoutLog.TAG_UNSUPPORTED,
            "Call to PolicyManager.makeNewWindow is not supported", null);
    return null;
}
```

as we can see the PolicyManager.makeNewWindow returns null directly,if i call
PolicyManager.makeNewWindow  i will get a null!  let's a look at Activity's attach method:
 final void attach(Context context, ActivityThread aThread,
            Instrumentation instr, IBinder token, int ident,
            Application application, Intent intent, ActivityInfo info,
            CharSequence title, Activity parent, String id,
            NonConfigurationInstances lastNonConfigurationInstances,
            Configuration config, String referrer, IVoiceInteractor voiceInteractor) {
        attachBaseContext(context);

```
    mFragments.attachActivity(this, mContainer, null);

    mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(this);
    mWindow.setCallback(this);
    mWindow.setOnWindowDismissedCallback(this);
    mWindow.getLayoutInflater().setPrivateFactory(this);
```

mWindow is null? mWindow.setCallback(this) will trigger a NullPointer Exception?i have to say i download the sourcecode by androidstudio ,i want to
kown is the source code wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Activity class in Android-23 Source Code

```
mWindow = new PhoneWindow(this)
```

not use PolicyManager class after api-22 to new PhoneWindow object.

when you develope under android api-23, you might create a PhoneWindow object through reflection. Here is code.

```
    String phone_window_calss = "com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow";
    Class phoneWindowClass = null;
    try {
        phoneWindowClass = Class.forName(phone_window_calss);
        Constructor constructor = phoneWindowClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class});
        mWindow = (Window) constructor.newInstance(context);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```